# Fill NaNs from another dataframe with group by

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

The first one looks like this

```
Month DayOfWeek  Class A1  A2 ... A999
July  Monday     Bata  7   9  ... 5
July  Tuesay     Bata  3   1  ... 2
July  Sunday     Bata  4   5  ... 6
July  Monday     Adid  9   8  ... 5
July  Sunday     Adid  4   0  ... 4
Sept  Monday     Nike  7   5  ... 7
Sept  Sunday     Nike  8   3  ... 7
Sept  Satday     Adid  2   7  ... 7
Sept  Monday     Bata  8   9  ... 4
Oct   Monday     Nike  4   2  ... 5
Oct   Sunday     Bata  8   6  ... 3
```

my second dataframe looks like this

```
Month DayOfWeek  Class A1  A2 ... A999
Jul   Monday     Bata  5   7      8
Oct   Monday     Adid  1   2      3
Sep   Monday     Bata  3   7      6
Sep   Monday     Nike  8   3      8
Jul   Monday     Adid  NaN NaN    NaN
Sep   Sunday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN
Oct   Satday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN
Sep   Monday     Bata  NaN NaN    NaN
```

The first dataframe called df1 has no NaNs
almost half of the second dataframe df2 are NaNs in the columns A1 to A999

number of columns is variable it could be from A1 to A10 or from A1 to A2567

it could be any number of columns

I want to fill these NaNs in df2 with the average of Same Month and DayOfWeek  from df1

I have posted another question before but the circumstances have changed and it has been split into 2 dataframes and unknown number of columns

I have done this so far

```
Mth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
Wk = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
for m in Mth:
    for w in Wk:
        print(w,m, df[(df["Month"]==m) & (df["DayOfWeek"]==w) ].mean())
```

I dont know where to go after and how can I not specify the column name to apply for all columns

```
Month DayOfWeek  Class A1  A2 ... A999
Jul   Monday     Bata  5   7      8
Oct   Monday     Adid  1   2      3
Sep   Monday     Bata  3   7      6
Sep   Monday     Nike  8   3      8
Jul   Monday     Adid  NaN NaN    NaN  <--- Avg of Monday Jul in df1 for each column
Sep   Sunday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN  <--- Avg of Sunday Sep in df1 for each column
Oct   Satday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN  <--- Avg of Satday Oct in df1 for each column
Sep   Monday     Bata  NaN NaN    NaN  <--- Avg of Monday Sep in df1 for each column
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby, merge and update function like below

**Generate Dummy Data**

```py
Mth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
Wk = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

def generate(nan=False):

    values = np.random.rand(20,20)
    if nan:
        nan_mask = np.random.choice([False,False,True], (20,20))
        values[nan_mask] = np.nan

    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = [f"A{i}" for i in range(values.shape[1])])
    df_ = pd.DataFrame()
    df_["Month"] = np.random.choice(Mth,20)
    df_["DayOfWeek"] = np.random.choice(Wk,20)

    df = pd.concat([df_, df], sort=False, axis=1)


    return df

df1 = generate()
df2 = generate(True)
```

**Solution**
first calculate means for each combination, then merge the means with index of original data then update original data with means

```py
means = df1.groupby(["Month", "DayOfWeek"]).mean().reset_index()
means = df1[["Month", "DayOfWeek"]].merge(means, how="left", on=["Month", "DayOfWeek"])

display(df2)
df3=df2.copy()
df3.update(means, overwrite=False)
display(df3)
```

Comment: df3.update(means, overwrite=False)
is causing error data overlaps

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work:

```
  result = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['Month','DayOfWeek','Class'], as_index=False,axis=0).mean().dropna()
```

The output is something like:

```
     Month DayOfWeek Class   A1   A2  A999
 2   July    Monday  Adid  9.0  8.0   5.0
 3   July    Monday  Bata  7.0  9.0   5.0
 4   July    Sunday  Adid  4.0  0.0   4.0
 5   July    Sunday  Bata  4.0  5.0   6.0
 6   July   Tuesday  Bata  3.0  1.0   2.0
 8    Oct    Monday  Nike  4.0  2.0   5.0
```

With the concat you combine your dataframes. I imagine you want to group by Month,DayOfWeek and Class. This piece of the code "as_index=False,axis=0" allows you to mix dataframes of different columns size. 
When it groups by "month, dayofweek and class", it creates all the possible columns:

```
       Month DayOfWeek Class   A1   A2  A999
  0    Jul    Monday  Adid    NaN  NaN   NaN
```

In this particular case there is no data and there is no interest on printing that, the solution is to add the dropna() at the end.

I hope it helps.